# Is it possible to specify which ArcGIS base-maps to use for the ESRI basemap gallery (ArcGIS API)?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible to specify which ArcGIS base-maps to use for the ESRI base-map gallery (**esri/dijit/BasemapGallery**)?

Setting **showArcGISBasemaps** to true brings back all of them but I only want a select few e.g. "*road*", "*national-geographic*" and "*satellite*".

```
var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
    showArcGISBasemaps: true,
    map: map,
}, "myPlaceHolder");
```

Looking through the documentation (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html) I can't seem to find anything.

Alternatively, is it possible to create these layers individually after setting **showArcGISBasemaps** to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to locate the layers manually after finding them on the ArcGIS services: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/service

```
var greyLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
    url: "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer"
});

var greyBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
    url: [greyLayer],
    id: "mybaselayerId",
    title: "Grey"
});

basemaps.push(greyBasemap);

var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
    showArcGISBasemaps: false,
    basemaps: basemaps,
    map: map,
}, "myPlaceHolder");
```

There doesn't seem to be an option to filter the basemaps returned from *showArcGISBasemaps*

Comment: Correct, the showArcGISBasemaps can't be filtered.  However, you can set up your ArcGIS organization to have a different set of basemaps, and then use that in the BasemapGallery widget (using the portalUrl) - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html#portalurl.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the basemaps in the `params.basemaps` object when you create the `BasemapGallery`: [new BasemapGallery()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html#basemapgallery1)

There's a code sample in that link too. Good luck!